# How to capitalize the first and last letters of every word in a string in java

Tags: java, string, character

How to capitalize the first and last letters of every word in a string

i have done it this way -

```
    String cap = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < sent.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (sent.charAt(i + 1) == ' ')
        {
            cap += Character.toUpperCase(sent.charAt(i)) + " " + Character.toUpperCase(sent.charAt(i + 2));
            i += 2;
        }
        else
            cap += sent.charAt(i);
    }
    cap += Character.toUpperCase(sent.charAt(sent.length() - 1));
    System.out.print (cap);
```

It does not work when the first word is of more than single character

Please use simple functions as i am a beginner

Comment: How are you reading in this `String`? From `System.in` or will the user by typing and submitting it, etc.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work if you only transform the character if it is succeeded by a whitespace. You'll want to do that for the first character (if `i == 0`) as well as if the previous character was whitespace as well. Check that in the loop and don't increment `i` yourself inside the loop ( i.e. no `i += 2;`) - this will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: As an aside, you should never do a String +=.  Look into documentation of `StringBuilder` which is actually being used by the Java compiler under the covers.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`apache commons lang` library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) it becomes very easy to do:

```
    String testString = "this string is needed to be 1st and 2nd letter-uppercased for each word";

    testString = WordUtils.capitalize(testString);
    testString = StringUtils.reverse(testString);
    testString = WordUtils.capitalize(testString);
    testString = StringUtils.reverse(testString);
    System.out.println(testString);
```

> ThiS StrinG IS NeedeD TO BE 1sT AnD 2nD Letter-uppercaseD FoR EacH
>   WorD

Comment: very funny way :)

Comment: Just a drawback : if you have many words to handle it may create a little overhead as you iterate more than required.

Comment: That's true, but can be helpful for not very long inputs

Answer (score 2):

You should rather split your String with a whitespace as character separator, then for each token apply toUpperCase() on the first and the last character and create a new String as result.

Very simple sample :

```
  String cap = "";
  String sent = "hello  world. again.";

  String[] token = sent.split("\\s+|\\.$");

  for (String currentToken : token){
      String firstChar = String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(currentToken.charAt(0)));
      String between = currentToken.substring(1, currentToken.length()-1);
      String LastChar = String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(currentToken.charAt(currentToken.length()-1)));
      if (!cap.equals("")){
        cap += " ";
      }
      cap += firstChar+between+LastChar; 
  }
```

Of course you should favor the use of StringBuilder over String as you perform many concatenations.

Output result : `HellO World. AgaiN`

Comment: what happens if sentence got `.`?

Comment: Note that if you have double whitespace you'd get an exception since the array would contain zero-length strings and thus `currentToken.charAt(0)` would break.

Comment: @Thomas Normally we expect to have two words separated by a whitespace. If we are not in this norm, `String[] token = sent.split("\\s+");` should do the job.

Comment: @davidxxx probably better using \b as delimiter

Comment: That's what I was getting at: multiple whitespaces and punctuation would require a more complex expression. As an example what about `?`, `!`, `,` etc.? You'd need to consider that as well, e.g. by matching word boundaries like nafas suggested.

Comment: @Thomas I agree with. But as indicated in my answer it is just a sample to get an idea on the way of proceeding, not a full comprehensive answer.  In fact the OP doesn't even refer to sentences but only String. We don't even know if we could have multiple between whitespaces between words or punctuation. Adjusting the regex to match to the real content is not very hard.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing out the first letter of the first word.  I would treat this as a special case, i.e.

```
cap = ""+Character.toUpperCase(sent.charAt(0));
for (int i = 1; i < sent.length() - 1; i++)
{
.....
```

Of course, there are much easier ways to do what you are doing.

Comment: This will not work if the first word has only 1 letter. Then the first letter of the second word is not capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to iterate over all characters and replace them if one of the following conditions is true:

- it's the first character
- it's the last character
- the previous character was a whitespace (or whatever you want, e.g. punctuation - see below)
- the next character is a whitespace (or whatever you want, e.g. punctuation - see below)

If you use a `StringBuilder` for performance and memory reasons (don't create a `String` in every iteration which `+=` would do) it could look like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "some words    in a list   even with    longer    whitespace in between" );
for( int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++ ) {
  if( i == 0 || //rule 1
      i == (sb.length() - 1 ) || //rule 2
      Character.isWhitespace( sb.charAt( i - 1 ) ) || //rule 3
      Character.isWhitespace( sb.charAt( i + 1 ) ) ) { //rule 4
    sb.setCharAt( i, Character.toUpperCase( sb.charAt( i ) ) );
  }
}
```

Result: `SomE WordS    IN A LisT   EveN WitH    LongeR    WhitespacE IN BetweeN`

If you want to check for other rules as well (e.g. punctuation etc.) you could create a method that you call for the previous and next character and which checks for the required properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
String stringToSearch = "this string is needed to be first and last letter uppercased for each word";

    // First letter upper case using regex
Pattern firstLetterPtn = Pattern.compile("(\\b[a-z]{1})+");
Matcher m = firstLetterPtn.matcher(stringToSearch);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb,m.group().toUpperCase()); 
}
m.appendTail(sb);
stringToSearch = sb.toString();
sb.setLength(0);

    // Last letter upper case using regex
Pattern LastLetterPtn = Pattern.compile("([a-z]{1}\\b)+");
m = LastLetterPtn.matcher(stringToSearch);
while(m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb,m.group().toUpperCase()); 
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());

output:

ThiS StrinG IS NeedeD TO BE FirsT AnD LasT LetteR UppercaseD FoR EacH WorD
```